# Qt app cannot open selected file from sandbox

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, flatpak, xdgutils

I'm writing a Qt app to run in `Flatpak` sandbox.
I'm stuck with opening files, as it opens the file chooser dialog, I select the file and then the app crashes with `File Not Found` error.

I checked the `/run/user/1000/doc/` directory, the correct folder gets created and it contains the selected file all well, just that the app doesn't see it. I'm using `XDG portal` to open file.

I'm not able to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand it the XDG portal gives you back an open file descriptor. If you are checking (directly or indirectly because of libraries) whether or not the *path* exists then that should fail if you run in sanboxed mode because of the private mount namespace (your app cannot see outside of it).

Comment: Lets say if i select a file `/home/some_user/Downloads/some_file.pdf` 
The Portal creates a copy of the file in the dir `/run/user/1000/doc/1ba0a453/some_file.pdf`

I get the this /run/user/... path in the app. But this file exists because portal has copied it but the app does not find it.

Comment: Quick question: what version of Qt are you using? I ask because with recent-ish versions of Qt there's been work on flatpak QPA plugin stuff like file chooser dialogs.

Comment: Also: it turns out I was wrong previously. The file chooser portal gives you an URI. But what it actually does is mark the requested file in a database of permissions, which is used by the document portal to control actual access to the file. So the URI is more like a token. You are not supposed to open it directly, but give it to the document portal which can open it for you.

Comment: There is some [documentation](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/portal-docs.html) But I haven't really seen good examples of how to use this.